# What is the Hombrew Computer Club for Ethereum?

Tags: homebrew

Though this question is not technical (and feel free to remove it), I feel compelled to ask here because of the technical prowess of members. I was wondering, what is the Homebrew Computer club equivalent for Ethereum developers? Are there online meetups, or a list of physical meetups for people interested in learning, sharing, and being a part of a larger, non-faceless community?

Comment: There are several groups working on different projects related to Ethereum. Most work is usually done online in different channels, forums, groups, ethresear.ch, ethereumcatherders.com, etc. Also there are several hackathons, conferences, talks, where ethereum's hackers meet. This year there's a conference DEVCON 6 in Bogota, Colombia. There will be several conferences in cities around the world before the big event.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael, I went to a conference in SF it was great!

Comment: Congratulations! Hope seeing your contribution to the ecosystem!